# How to plot position(x y z) and velocity of fixed frames(end-effector) in rqt?

Tags: ros, joint, velocity, position, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi . i need answer to complete my Master's thesis. i want plot position and  velocity of end effector that have fixed joint  using rqt.
How to plot position(x y z) and velocity of fixed frames(end-effector) in rqt ??
can you write a very very very simple examlpe for that ??  like two link and one joint arm . and plot position(x y z) of second link in rqt ??

[image: UR5 straight line motion]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252572/how-to-plot-position(x-y-z)-and-velocity-of-fixed-frames(end-effector)-in-rqt-??/) by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2017-01-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-04-13**:
Please stop editing your question just to put it back on the first page.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-04-13**:
can you write a very very very simple examlpe for that ??  for god doing that ,  please !

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-04-13**:
You don't show that you tried to do it yourself, you don't even care about writing correctly. Why should someone else do your work?

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-04-13**:
i tried . but i just need examlpe for that . i cant find any sample , like two link and one joint arm . and plot position(x y z) of second link in rqt

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-04-13**:
You were told how to do it several times: get a tf client, use it to get your translation, publish your values on separate float-topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A fixed joint has no element in the `/joint_states/position` array, as it cannot change from `0.0` (it's fixed, after all).

You could probably use the *pose* of your EEF as tracked by TF. Something like `rosrun tf tf_echo CHAIN_START CHAIN_END` (where `CHAIN_START` could be `base_link` and `CHAIN_END` the frame that represents your EEF) should give you the transform.

---

Edit:

> how can i plot velocity of fixed joint ??

There is no entry in any of the arrays in a `JointState` message for fixed joints. Again: they are fixed. No `velocity`, `acceleration` or `effort` for these joints.

Note: I'm describing the typical situation (such as with `joint_state_publisher` with `gui:=true`). Whether all drivers do the same thing I cannot say, but it wouldn't make sense to me to publish joint values for something like a fixed joint.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-01-21**:
how can i plot pose for my fixed joint(joint_U26_1) like [rqt_plot /turtle1/pose/x:y](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot) ??

what is a turtle1 ??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-22**:
Joints don't have poses, only `link`s have poses (every `link` becomes a TF frame). Plotting TF frames is slightly involved. See #q58793 for some hints.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-22**:
Some other options:

- [tf_trajectory](http://jsk-visualization.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jsk_rviz_plugins/plugins/tf_trajectory.html)
- [hector_trajectory_server](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_trajectory_server)

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-01-22**:
how use this command ??
rxplot /tf/transforms[0]/transform/translation/x
thats not working .

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-22**:
`rxplot` is now `rqt_plot`.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-01-22**:
rqt_plot /tf/transforms[0]/transform/translation/x  not working .

can i use [this page](http://answers.ros.org/question/249736/plot-posestamped-topic-in-rqt_plotrviz/?answer=249756)??  what can i do ?

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-01-23**:
what about  [this one](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Getting%20the%20current%20joint%20angles)??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-23**:
That page still works with `JointState` messages, which do not typically include fixed joints. You'll have to plot *TF frames*, not `JointState` msgs. The pkgs I linked in my earlier comment could help you with that.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-01-23**:
can you write a very simple sample for that ?? i want plot pose ( x and  y and  z ) of link

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-01-23**:
in  [#q58793](http://answers.ros.org/question/58793/) wrote i shoud  use pose topic parsed from the node tf . how can i do that? i cant found any sample .

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-24**:
Other than `tf_trajectory` and `hector_trajectory_server`, I don't know of any existing pkgs/nodes that can do what you want, but in a nutshell:

1. create a TF listener for the TF frame you want to plot
2. convert the TF to a `geometry_msgs/Pose` and publish that
3. plot

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-01-24**:
im sorry . can i plot in RViz or rqt_plot ?? which one ??

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-25**:
TF frames you can show in RViz (using either the `TF Display` or one of the pkgs I linked above). If you create the `TF -> geometry_msgs/Pose` converter, you can use RQT to plot the individual members of the `Pose` msg.

**Comment by [zakizadeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27970/zakizadeh/) on 2017-01-27**:
i need practical example .